# ERROR: Failed to make the following project runnable: This process cannot access the file ~/MyProject.exe' because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

When I am trying to compile and run my ASP.Net Core 1.0 project on Visual Studio 2015, I am getting the following error:

`Failed to make the following project runnable: MyProject (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6) reason: The process cannot access the file '~\MyProject.exe' because it is being used by another process.

File: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets`

I have no clue why this error is coming. Any solution?

Comment: Do you target your project to net46 and set RuntimeIdentifier to change the output to `MyProject.exe`, will you see `MyProject.exe` while opening Task Manager? Will you receive this error if reopen VS and this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a silly solution to this problem that actually worked! I stopped debugging and closed `Visual Studio`. Then I restarted the computer. Upon opening `Visual Studio` again after restarting the computer, I was able to run the application without any error.

It seems the process was still running in the background even though the application had been stopped from `Visual Studio`.

Source: Basic troubleshooting